# test is updated in UI but not updating in console why ? can anyone tell about why console is not updating?

Tags: reactjs, setinterval

**basically my question is  that why test state is not updating in console ??**

```
import {useEffect, useRef, useState} from "react";

const Home = () => {
    let [test, setTest] = useState(0);
    const ref = useRef(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        setInterval( () => {
            console.log(test, ref);
            ref.current += 1;
             setTest( test =>test + 1);
            console.log(test, ref);
        }, 1000)
    }, [])
    return <>
        <div>
            <h1>a : {test}</h1>
            <h1>ref : {ref.current}</h1>
        </div>
    </>
}

export default Home
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZY7Ab.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the `useEffect` in this code is only executed once. The state value when `useEffect` was executed was 0, and the function continues to remember this value.

In the first log, the value at the time `useEffect` was executed was 0, so it is displayed as 0. Also, using `setState` does not change the value immediately within the same scope. That's why the second log also shows 0.

According to the official documentation, the object returned through `useRef` is maintained throughout the entire **lifecycle of the component**. So, the value of `useRef` can represent different values ​​even within the same scope.